# Angular 2 Accessing an array inside an array directly without ngFor

Tags: angular

Is there a way to access an Array inside an Array directly and without ngFor?
f.e.

```
<li *ngFor="let reward of tier.rewards">
        {{ reward.array.[SECOND_ELEMENT] }}
   </li>
```

Comment: `reward.array[1]` didn't work? Could you give a [mcve]?

Comment: `Reward.array[SECOND_ELEMENT]` should work

Comment: Thanks guys! It works without the dot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need dot operator if you are using **`[]`**

```
<li *ngFor="let reward of tier.rewards">
        {{ reward.array[SECOND_ELEMENT] }}
</li>
```